# How to set attributes, if ng-if condition is true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I set attribute if ng-if returns true in below code `data-validator=""` and `data-validator-msg=""` set only when condition is true and if it returns false then both attribute not to be set but at all conditions radio button should appear.

> In current code, condition is working but radio button visible only at
>   true condition.

```
<input ng-model="user.duration" value="{{ x.title}}" type="radio" ng-if="$index==5" data-validator="required" data-validator-msg="Select one radio button">{{ x.title}}
```

[image: radio buttons]

What exactly mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a directive for you:

```
.directive("isValidatorDirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      applyValidator: '=',
      msg: '@',
      validator: '@'
    }
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      if (scope.applyValidator) {
        elem.attr('data-validator-msg', scope.msg); 
        elem.attr('data-validator', scope.validator);
      }
      else {
        elem.removeAttr('data-validator-msg');
        elem.removeAttr('data-validator');
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Use it as follows:

```
<input is-validator-directive apply-validator="$index === 5" validator="required" msg="Select one radio button" ng-model="user.duration" value="{{ x.title}}" type="radio">{{x.title}}
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution:

```
<input ng-model="user.duration" value="{{x.title}}" type="radio" ng-if="$index==5" data-validator="required" data-validator-msg="Select one radio button">{{x.title}}

<input ng-model="user.duration" value="{{x.title}}" type="radio" ng-if="$index!=5">{{x.title}}
```

(*ng-if* removes the element from the DOM if the condition evaluates to false)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple condition logic:

```
<input
  ng-model="user.duration" 
  value="{{ x.title}}" 
  type="radio" 
  data-validator="{ ($index===5 && 'required') || '' }" 
  data-validator-msg="{ ($index===5 && 'Select one radio button') || '' }" 
>{{ x.title}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ng-if only renders the respective element when the condition is true. What you want is to pass different values as attributes depending on a condition. You can do this for example with the conditional operator:

```
<input ng-model="user.duration"
       value="{{ x.title}}"
       type="radio"
       data-validator="{{ $index==5 ? 'required' : '' }"
       data-validator-msg="{{ $index==5 ? 'required' : 'Select one radio button' }">
  {{x.title}}
</input>
```